Generation of OpenAPI Controller, Model classes in a separate module
We have a spring boot multi module maven project.
We would like to have controller/delegates in one module and models in another module. (eg: myproject-web, myproject-data etc.. ).
When we generate the classes using the plugin openapi-generator-maven-plugin, we would like to generate the controller and delegates in myproject-web and model classes in myproject-data.
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.4.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>myproject-api</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>
                                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/specs/myproject-api-spec.yaml
                                </inputSpec>
                                <output>${project.basedir}\myproject-data\src\main\java</output>
                                <!-- <output>
                                    ../../myproject-data/src/main/java
                                </output>-->
                                <!--<output>
                                    C:\Projects\ABC\myprojectservice\myproject-parent\myproject-data\src\main\java
                                </output>-->
                                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                                <modelPackage>com.abc.myproject.common.model</modelPackage>
                                <apiPackage>com.abc.myproject.web.controller</apiPackage>
                                <!--<skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>true</skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>-->
                                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                                <configOptions>
                                    <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                        @lombok.Data
                                        @lombok.NoArgsConstructor
                                        @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
                                    </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                    <documentationProvider>springdoc</documentationProvider>
                                    <unhandledException>true</unhandledException>
                                    <openApiNullable>true</openApiNullable>
                                    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                    <output></output>
                                </configOptions>
                                <output>.</output>
                                <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/.openapi-generator-ignore
                                </ignoreFileOverride>
                                <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/templates</templateDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

We tried, using output directory configuration for the same but its not working.
Any idea, how this can be addressed.
